# Angular ReactiveForms: Producing an array of checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular2-forms

Given a list of checkboxes bound to the same `formControlName`, how can I produce an array of checkbox values bound to the `formControl`, rather than simply `true`/`false`?

**Example:**

```
<form [formGroup]="checkboxGroup">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" value="value-1" formControlName="myValues" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-2" value="value-2" formControlName="myValues" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-3" value="value-2" formControlName="myValues" />
</form>
```

**`checkboxGroup.controls['myValues'].value` currently produces:**

```
true or false
```

**What I want it to produce:**

```
['value-1', 'value-2', ...]
```

Comment: This is probably the most over-engineered way to do checkboxes in a form ever. This is not straightforward at all.

Comment: @mwilson are you specifically complaining about my implementation or Angular?

Comment: Angular. All I'm trying to do is get a mat-radio-group to bind in my reactive form. I don't remember struggling this much with angular. All the articles are pointing to the same thing. Just can't get it to work. Everything else is super straightforward. I've probably been looking at it way too long. Still just feels like wayyyyy too much complexity for an array value in a form.

Comment: Yeah it was terrible when I asked this in 2016, and it's still terrible in 2019.

Comment: I'm not adding a ton to this question, but I wanted it known to others that I feel the same way. This alone has been the hardest part in learning angular reactive forms. I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult, at all. I'm happy to see I'm not alone in the struggle, though. So thanks for posting the question.

Comment: this is crazy, and all the solutions are complex for gathering simple checked values, this is a good example of big framework making simple stuff more complex.  my stupid simple solution is to have a hidden ng input for the actual question, and use basic html (no ng bindings)+js to render and handle onchange event, which then gathers and puts data I want in hidden ng input for ng to pick up.

Comment: ReactiveForms and dealing with groups of checkboxes and radio buttons is pretty much the single most horrible thing about Angular. I love the type safety and OOP structure but this alone is enough of a head ache for me to consider alternatives.

Comment: Hey @MartinSotirov, I completely agree with you! It's insane how Angular still doesn't have a simple way to solve this. After a lot of research and test, I was able to come up with a elegant solution, you might want to check and see what you think: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69637536/3317037

Comment: looking at your code, i found out my own problem that was a totally different thing  :) thanks <3

Answer (score 86, accepted):

With the help of silentsod answer, I wrote a solution to get values instead of states in my formBuilder.

I use a method to add or remove values in the formArray. It may be a bad approch, but it works !

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let choice of checks; let i=index" class="col-md-2">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" [value]="choice.value" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">
    {{choice.description}}
  </label>
</div>
```

**component.ts**

```
// For example, an array of choices
public checks: Array<ChoiceClass> = [
  {description: 'descr1', value: 'value1'},
  {description: "descr2", value: 'value2'},
  {description: "descr3", value: 'value3'}
];

initModelForm(): FormGroup{
  return this._fb.group({
    otherControls: [''],
    // The formArray, empty 
    myChoices: new FormArray([]),
  }
}

onCheckChange(event) {
  const formArray: FormArray = this.myForm.get('myChoices') as FormArray;

  /* Selected */
  if(event.target.checked){
    // Add a new control in the arrayForm
    formArray.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
  }
  /* unselected */
  else{
    // find the unselected element
    let i: number = 0;

    formArray.controls.forEach((ctrl: FormControl) => {
      if(ctrl.value == event.target.value) {
        // Remove the unselected element from the arrayForm
        formArray.removeAt(i);
        return;
      }

      i++;
    });
  }
}
```

When I submit my form, for example my model looks like:

```
  otherControls : "foo",
  myChoices : ['value1', 'value2']
```

Only one thing is missing, a function to fill the formArray if your model already has checked values.

Comment: how do i check if my checkbox is checked when i load the data after using your example to enter into db?

Comment: In this solution always the form is being valid even if checkbox aren't selected

Comment: ```myChoices: new FormArray([], Validators.required)```

Comment: "But it works!" is how tech debt starts. This is not the reactive form way of doing it. One of the benefits of using formcontrols on every checkbox input is they can remember their states even when you re-add them to the DOM.

Comment: Hey, I designed an extensible and object-oriented solution to solve this use case, you can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69637536/3317037

Comment: @MIWMIB That's nice and all, but the built-in FormArray has no obvious way to keep track of the checkbox labels. You're basically stuck with keeping track of it yourself.

Answer (score 60):

Here's a good place to use the `FormArray` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormArray-class.html

To start we'll build up our array of controls either with a `FormBuilder` or newing up a `FormArray`

**FormBuilder**

```
this.checkboxGroup = _fb.group({
  myValues: _fb.array([true, false, true])
});
```

**new FormArray**

```
let checkboxArray = new FormArray([
  new FormControl(true),
  new FormControl(false),
  new FormControl(true)]);

this.checkboxGroup = _fb.group({
  myValues: checkboxArray
});
```

Easy enough to do, but then we're going to change our template and let the templating engine handle how we bind to our controls:

**template.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="checkboxGroup">
    <input *ngFor="let control of checkboxGroup.controls['myValues'].controls"
    type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" value="value-1" [formControl]="control" />     
  </form>
```

Here we're iterating over our set of `FormControls` in our `myValues` `FormArray` and for each control we're binding `[formControl]` to that control instead of to the `FormArray` control and `<div>{{checkboxGroup.controls['myValues'].value}}</div>` produces `true,false,true` while also making your template syntax a little less manual.

You can use this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/a9OdMAq2YIwQFo7gixbj?p=preview to poke around

Comment: probably you should remove id="xxx", the id should be unique right?

Comment: for id could be used index  ```*ngFor="let control of checkboxGroup.controls['myValues'].controls ; let i=index""```

Comment: This is cool, but produces a completely generic array of checkboxes. Presumably you would be loading in an array or something else, and associating each checkbox with some other value. How do you add, for instance, a text string for use in a form label to each form control?

Comment: NM I've just mapped it next to an external array :p

Comment: @Askdesigners can you post your solution to have the checkboxes and the labels?

Comment: @eddygeek It's too intertwined in the app code (which is not public), but basically what I did was:
1) read in the data from the api (an array of things)
2) use a spread, for or map, to make 2 new arrays. One array is used to generate the checkboxes, and the other is for the label text. They just have the same indexes.
3) ngFor over each array seperately in the UI. One loop to make the labels, the other to make the checkboxes.

Comment: @eddygeek I've created two fields in group (each group in created array). One field is boolean and the other one is string (my label).

In HTML (in each [formGroup]):
<label>{{groupItem.controls.languageLabel.value}}</label>

Comment: Tried in my project, still get `[true, false..] `...Am I missing something? Or does it still work in latest Angular?

Answer (score 42):

It's significantly easier to do this in Angular 6 than it was in previous versions, even when the checkbox information is populated asynchronously from an API.

The first thing to realise is that thanks to Angular 6's `keyvalue` pipe we don't need to have to use `FormArray` anymore, and can instead nest a `FormGroup`.

First, pass FormBuilder into the constructor

```
constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
) { }
```

Then initialise our form.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
        'checkboxes': this._formBuilder.group({}),
    });

}
```

When our checkbox options data is available, iterate it and we can push it directly into the nested `FormGroup` as a named `FormControl`, without having to rely on number indexed lookup arrays.

```
const checkboxes = <FormGroup>this.form.get('checkboxes');
options.forEach((option: any) => {
    checkboxes.addControl(option.title, new FormControl(true));
});
```

Finally, in the template we just need to iterate the `keyvalue` of the checkboxes: no additional `let index = i`, and the checkboxes will automatically be in alphabetical order: much cleaner.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <h3>Options</h3>

    <div formGroupName="checkboxes">

        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of form.get('checkboxes').value | keyvalue">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="item.key" [value]="item.value" /> {{ item.key }}
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Very usable as well in case of a simple hardcoded array of checkbox values. Then you can add the form controls using a similar for loop right away in ngOnInit(), and the checkboxes in your form will dynamically reflect the checkbox values array

Comment: This still excerpts [key1=true,key2=false,key3=true]. We want ['key1','key3']

Comment: @f.khantsis You can do it like that:

`
const value = {
  key1: true, key2: false, key3: true
};

const list = Object.entries(value).filter(([_, isSelected]) => isSelected).map(([key]) => key);

console.log(list);
`

Comment: Best solution imho. You can place the assignment of `const checkboxes = ..` outside the foreach ;)

Comment: What happens when the item key equals the same thing as another field on the form? For instance, I have two different checkbox arrays, each with the keys 'Small', 'Medium', and 'Large'?

Comment: @Newclique On your form, use addControl() to add a formGroup for each checkbox array, naming them differently

Comment: I see. I guess it appeared to me that the [formControlName] binding would have no way to associate to the correct name if the binding is in a loop. How can two different loops with [formControlName]="item.key" bind to the correct control if the keys happen to be the same? What am I missing? Adding two form groups with different names means those names need to be the same as the controls' formControlName, right?

Comment: This solution looks nice and clean, but I'm running into an error: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'. <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="item.key" [value]="item.value" /> {{ item.key }}

Comment: How would I store a label to go along with this? The only way I can see to do this is to manage two separate arrays but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 20):

I don't see a solution here that completely answers the question using reactive forms to its fullest extent so here's my solution for the same.

---

### Summary

Here's the pith of the detailed explanation along with a StackBlitz example.

1. Use `FormArray` for the checkboxes and initialize the form.
2. The `valueChanges` observable is perfect for when you want the form to display something but store something else in the component. Map the `true`/`false` values to the desired values here.
3. Filter out the `false` values at the time of submission.
4. Unsubscribe from `valueChanges` observable.

#### [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-custom-value)

---

### Detailed explanation

**Use FormArray to define the form**

As already mentioned in the answer marked as correct. `FormArray` is the way to go in such cases where you would prefer to get the data in an array. So the first thing you need to do is create the form.

```js
checkboxGroup: FormGroup;
checkboxes = [{
    name: 'Value 1',
    value: 'value-1'
}, {
    name: 'Value 2',
    value: 'value-2'
}];

this.checkboxGroup = this.fb.group({
    checkboxes: this.fb.array(this.checkboxes.map(x => false))
});
```

This will just set the initial value of all the checkboxes to `false`.

Next, we need to register these form variables in the template and iterate over the `checkboxes` array (NOT the `FormArray` but the checkbox data) to display them in the template.

```html
<form [formGroup]="checkboxGroup">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxes; let i = index" formArrayName="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" />{{checkbox.name}}
    </ng-container>
</form>
```

**Make use of the valueChanges observable**

Here's the part I don't see mentioned in any answer given here. In situations such as this, where we would like to display said data but store it as something else, the `valueChanges` observable is very helpful. Using `valueChanges`, we can observe the changes in the `checkboxes` and then `map` the `true`/`false` values received from the `FormArray` to the desired data. Note that this will not change the selection of the checkboxes as any [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value passed to the checkbox will mark it as checked and vice-versa.

```js
subscription: Subscription;

const checkboxControl = (this.checkboxGroup.controls.checkboxes as FormArray);
this.subscription = checkboxControl.valueChanges.subscribe(checkbox => {
    checkboxControl.setValue(
        checkboxControl.value.map((value, i) => value ? this.checkboxes[i].value : false),
        { emitEvent: false }
    );
});
```

This basically maps the `FormArray` values to the original `checkboxes` array and returns the `value` in case the checkbox is marked as `true`, else it returns `false`. The `emitEvent: false` is important here since setting the `FormArray` value without it will cause  `valueChanges` to emit an event creating an endless loop. By setting `emitEvent` to `false`, we are making sure the `valueChanges` observable does not emit when we set the value here.

**Filter out the false values**

We cannot directly filter the `false` values in the `FormArray` because doing so will mess up the template since they are bound to the checkboxes. So the best possible solution is to filter out the `false` values during submission. Use the spread operator to do this.

```js
submit() {
    const checkboxControl = (this.checkboxGroup.controls.checkboxes as FormArray);
    const formValue = {
        ...this.checkboxGroup.value,
        checkboxes: checkboxControl.value.filter(value => !!value)
    }
    // Submit formValue here instead of this.checkboxGroup.value as it contains the filtered data
}
```

This basically filters out the [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values from the `checkboxes`.

**Unsubscribe from valueChanges**

Lastly, don't forget to unsubscribe from `valueChanges`

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

**Note:** There is a special case where a value cannot be set to the `FormArray` in `valueChanges`, i.e if the checkbox value is set to the number `0`. This will make it look like the checkbox cannot be selected since selecting the checkbox will set the `FormControl` as the number `0` (a falsy value) and hence keep it unchecked. It would be preferred not to use the number `0` as a value but if it is required, you have to conditionally set `0` to some truthy value, say string `'0'` or just plain `true` and then on submitting, convert it back to the number `0`.

#### [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-custom-value)

The StackBlitz also has code for when you want to pass default values to the checkboxes so they get marked as checked in the UI.

Comment: This still requires maintaining two arrays and keeping them in sync. Still not as clean as I'm hoping for. Perhaps we can get the form controls to hold complex values instead of having two arrays.

Comment: Complex value didn't work because the value has to be either true or false for the checkbox. So this solution still looks the best.

Answer (score 16):

TL;DR

1. I prefer to use FormGroup to populate the list of checkbox
2. Write a custom validator to check at least one checkbox was selected
3. Working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-validate-at-least-one-checkbox-was-selected

---

This also struck me sometimes so I did try both FormArray and FormGroup approaches.

Most of the time, the list of checkboxes was populated on the server and I received it through API. But sometimes you will have a static set of checkboxes with your predefined value. With each use case, the corresponding FormArray or FormGroup will be used.

> Basically `FormArray` is a variant of `FormGroup`. The key difference is that its data gets serialized as an array (as opposed to being serialized as an object in case of FormGroup). This might be especially useful when you don’t know how many controls will be present within the group, like dynamic forms.

For the sake of simplicity, imagine you have a simple create product form with

- One required product name textbox.
- A list of categories to select from, required at least one to be checked. Assume the list will be retrieved from the server.

[image: List of category]

First, I set up a form with only the product name `formControl`. It is a required field.

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: ["", Validators.required]
});
```

Since the category is dynamically rendering, I will have to add these data into the form later after the data was ready.

```js
this.getCategories().subscribe(categories => {
    this.form.addControl("categoriesFormArr", this.buildCategoryFormArr(categories));
    this.form.addControl("categoriesFormGroup", this.buildCategoryFormGroup(categories));
})
```

There are two approaches to build up the category list.

### 1. Form Array

```js
  buildCategoryFormArr(categories: ProductCategory[], selectedCategoryIds: string[] = []): FormArray {
    const controlArr = categories.map(category => {
      let isSelected = selectedCategoryIds.some(id => id === category.id);
      return this.formBuilder.control(isSelected);
    })
    return this.formBuilder.array(controlArr, atLeastOneCheckboxCheckedValidator())
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let control of categoriesFormArr?.controls; let i = index" class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" [formControl]="control" />
    {{ categories[i]?.title }}
  </label>
</div>
```

This `buildCategoryFormGroup` will return me a FormArray. It also takes a list of selected values as an argument so If you want to reuse the form for editing data, it could be helpful. For the purpose of creating a new product form, it is not applicable yet.

Noted that when you try to access the formArray values. It will looks like `[false, true, true]`. To get a list of selected id, it required a bit more work to check from the list but based on the array index. Doesn't sound good to me but it works.

```js
get categoriesFormArraySelectedIds(): string[] {
  return this.categories
  .filter((cat, catIdx) => this.categoriesFormArr.controls.some((control, controlIdx) => catIdx === controlIdx && control.value))
  .map(cat => cat.id);
}
```

That's why I came up using `FormGroup` for that matter

### 2. Form Group

`formGroup` will store the form data as the object, which required a key map to a form control. So it is a good idea to set the key as the `categoryId` and then we can retrieve it later.

```js
buildCategoryFormGroup(categories: ProductCategory[], selectedCategoryIds: string[] = []): FormGroup {
  let group = this.formBuilder.group({}, {
    validators: atLeastOneCheckboxCheckedValidator()
  });
  categories.forEach(category => {
    let isSelected = selectedCategoryIds.some(id => id === category.id);
    group.addControl(category.id, this.formBuilder.control(isSelected));
  })
  return group;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of categories; let i = index" class="checkbox">
  <label><input type="checkbox" [formControl]="categoriesFormGroup?.controls[item.id]" /> {{ categories[i]?.title }}
  </label>
</div>
```

The value of the form group will look like this:

```js
{
    "category1": false,
    "category2": true,
    "category3": true,
}
```

But most often we want to get only the list of `categoryIds` as `["category2", "category3"]`. I also have to write a get to take these data. I like this approach better compared to the formArray, because I could actually take the value from the form itself.

```js
  get categoriesFormGroupSelectedIds(): string[] {
    let ids: string[] = [];
    for (var key in this.categoriesFormGroup.controls) {
      if (this.categoriesFormGroup.controls[key].value) {
        ids.push(key);
      }
      else {
        ids = ids.filter(id => id !== key);
      }
    }
    return ids;
  }
```

### 3. Custom validator to check at least one checkbox was selected

I made the validator check at least X checkbox was selected, by default it will check against one checkbox only.

```js
export function atLeastOneCheckboxCheckedValidator(minRequired = 1): ValidatorFn {
  return function validate(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    let checked = 0;

    Object.keys(formGroup.controls).forEach(key => {
      const control = formGroup.controls[key];

      if (control.value) {
        checked++;
      }
    });

    if (checked < minRequired) {
      return {
        requireCheckboxToBeChecked: true,
      };
    }

    return null;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are looking for checkbox values in JSON format

```
{ "name": "", "countries": [ { "US": true }, { "Germany": true }, { "France": true } ] }
```

[Full example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hw6HyVkimFnO1awBpCX3?p=preview).

I apologise for using Country Names as checkbox values instead of those in the question. Further explannation -

Create a FormGroup for the form

```
 createForm() {

    //Form Group for a Hero Form
    this.heroForm = this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      countries: this.fb.array([])
    });

    let countries=['US','Germany','France'];

    this.setCountries(countries);}
 }
```

Let each checkbox be a FormGroup built from an object whose only property is the checkbox's value.

```
 setCountries(countries:string[]) {

    //One Form Group for one country
    const countriesFGs = countries.map(country =>{
            let obj={};obj[country]=true;
            return this.fb.group(obj)
    });

    const countryFormArray = this.fb.array(countriesFGs);
    this.heroForm.setControl('countries', countryFormArray);
  }
```

The array of FormGroups for the checkboxes is used to set the control for the 'countries' in the parent Form.

```
  get countries(): FormArray {
      return this.heroForm.get('countries') as FormArray;
  };
```

In the template, use a pipe to get the name for the checkbox control

```
  <div formArrayName="countries" class="well well-lg">
      <div *ngFor="let country of countries.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i" >
          <div *ngFor="let key of country.controls | mapToKeys" >
              <input type="checkbox" formControlName="{{key.key}}">{{key.key}}
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You guys need to copy the pipe mapToKeys from example link or as below if that link dies. You may need to remove the second param (args) and declare the pipe in app module file: import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'mapToKeys'})
export class MapToKeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value) : any {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
        }
        return keys;
    }
}

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use an Angular reactive form (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

You can use one form control to manage the outputted value of the group of checkboxes.

**component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { flow } from 'lodash';
import { flatMap, filter } from 'lodash/fp';

@Component({
  selector: 'multi-checkbox',
  templateUrl: './multi-checkbox.layout.html',
})
export class MultiChecboxComponent  {

  checklistState = [ 
      {
        label: 'Frodo Baggins',
        value: 'frodo_baggins',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Samwise Gamgee',
        value: 'samwise_gamgee',
        checked: true,
      },
      {
        label: 'Merry Brandybuck',
        value: 'merry_brandybuck',
        checked: false
      }
    ];

  form = new FormGroup({
    checklist : new FormControl(this.flattenValues(this.checklistState)),
  });


  checklist = this.form.get('checklist');

  onChecklistChange(checked, checkbox) {
    checkbox.checked = checked;
    this.checklist.setValue(this.flattenValues(this.checklistState));
  }

  flattenValues(checkboxes) {
    const flattenedValues = flow([
      filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked),
      flatMap(checkbox => checkbox.value )
    ])(checkboxes)
    return flattenedValues.join(',');
  }
}
```

**html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <label *ngFor="let checkbox of checklistState" class="checkbox-control">
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="onChecklistChange($event.target.checked, checkbox)" [checked]="checkbox.checked" [value]="checkbox.value" /> {{ checkbox.label }}
  </label>
</form>
```

### `checklistState`

Manages the model/state of the checklist inputs. This model allows you to map the current state to whatever value format you need.

Model:

```
{
   label: 'Value 1',
   value: 'value_1',
   checked: false
},
{
  label: 'Samwise Gamgee',
  value: 'samwise_gamgee',
  checked: true,
},
{
  label: 'Merry Brandybuck',
  value: 'merry_brandybuck',
  checked: false
}
```

### `checklist` Form Control

This control stores the value would like to save as e.g

value output: `"value_1,value_2"`

See demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-checklist

Comment: Easily the best solution for me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Make an event when it's clicked and then manually change the value of true to the name of what the check box represents, then the name or true will evaluate the same and you can get all the values instead of a list of true/false. Ex:

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="customForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let parameter of parameters"> <!--I iterate here to list all my checkboxes -->
        <label class="control-label" for="{{parameter.Title}}"> {{parameter.Title}} </label>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  id="{{parameter.Title}}"
                  formControlName="{{parameter.Title}}"
                  (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)"
                  > <!-- ^^THIS^^ is the important part -->
             </div>
      </div>
 </form>
```

component.ts

```
onCheckboxChange(event) {
    //We want to get back what the name of the checkbox represents, so I'm intercepting the event and
    //manually changing the value from true to the name of what is being checked.

    //check if the value is true first, if it is then change it to the name of the value
    //this way when it's set to false it will skip over this and make it false, thus unchecking
    //the box
    if(this.customForm.get(event.target.id).value) {
        this.customForm.patchValue({[event.target.id] : event.target.id}); //make sure to have the square brackets
    }
}
```

This catches the event after it was already changed to true or false by Angular Forms, if it's true I change the name to the name of what the checkbox represents, which if needed will also evaluate to true if it's being checked for true/false as well.

Comment: This got me on the right track, I ended up doing this this.customForm.patchValue({[event.target.id] : event.target.checked});

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this is a very common problem and no one has a "perfect" solution. I believe I was able to come with a pretty elegant solution, using object orientation to extend the capabilities of FormGroup.

## Desired API

In a single object I want to be able to have:

- The form control for each checkbox
- The label and value for each checkbox
- The values of all selected checkbox

So the HTML structure can be simple as this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of checkboxGroup.items">
   <input type="checkbox" [id]="item.value" [formControl]="item.control">
   <label [for]="item.value">{{ item.label }}</label>
 </div>
```

And the typescript part can be simple as this:

```
checkboxGroup.value; // return the list of selected item values
checkboxGroup.control.valid; // return if there's at least one checked value
```

## Solution

As you can see in the HTML part, the `checkboxGroup` needs to be a class with at least three properties:

- items (each item is a checkbox with a value, label and a FormControl)
- value (gets all selected items)
- control (gets the FormArray control)

So the class will be like:

```
// # This represents a single checkbox item
class CheckboxItemControl {
  label: string; // value to be shown in the UI
  value: string; // value to be saved in backend

  control: FormControl;

  constructor({ label, value, defaultValue = false }: { label: string; value: string; defaultValue?: boolean }) {
    this.label = label;
    this.value = value;

    this.control = new FormControl(defaultValue || false);
  }

  get selected(): boolean {
    return Boolean(this.control.value);
  }
}

// # This represents a checkbox group, with several items
class CheckboxGroupControl {
  name?: string; // name of the checkbox group

  items: CheckboxItemControl[];
  control: FormArray;

  constructor(name: string, items: CheckboxItemControl[]) {
    this.name = name;
    this.items = items;

    this.control = new FormArray(this.getAllItemsControls(), CheckboxGroupControl.emptyArrayFormValidator);
  }

  get value(): string[] {
    return this.selectedItems.map(item => item.value);
  }

  private get selectedItems(): CheckboxItemControl[] {
    return this.items.filter(item => item.selected);
  }

  private getAllItemsControls(): FormControl[] {
    return this.items.map(item => item.control);
  }

  private static emptyArrayFormValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const valid = (control.value as boolean[]).some(Boolean);

    // @todo improve error message
    return valid ? null : {
      error: 'empty'
    };
  }
}
```

You can see how each class exposes a simple API (`object.value` and `object.control`) which allows you to easily get all that you need.

## Usage

So let's see in practice how it'll work:

#### HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let item of checkboxGroup.items">
   <input type="checkbox" [id]="item.value" [formControl]="item.control">
   <label [for]="item.value">{{ item.label }}</label>
 </div>
```

#### Typescript

```
checkboxGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.createFormInputs();
}

private createFormInputs() {
  const checkboxItems = [
    new CheckboxItemControl({ value: 'checkbox-1', label: 'Checkbox 1' }),
    new CheckboxItemControl({ value: 'checkbox-2', label: 'Checkbox 2' }),
    new CheckboxItemControl({ value: 'checkbox-3', label: 'Checkbox 3', defaultValue: true })
  ];

  this.checkboxGroup = new CheckboxGroupControl('name_of_group', checkboxItems);

  this.form = new FormGroup({
    checkbox: this.checkboxGroup.control
  });

  // this.checkboxGroup.value returns ['checkbox-1', ...] for the selected checkboxes
  // this.checkboxGroup.valid returns if there's any checkbox selected
  // this.form.valid returns if the whole form is valid. Which is useful if you include others checkbox groups
}
```

## Other resources

- [This article](https://medium.com/@DheerajJaiswal6/multi-checkbox-form-control-angular7-39cbdabede57) sparks the light for me to come up with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

My solution - solved it for Angular 5 with Material View
The connection is through the

> formArrayName="notification"
>
> (change)="updateChkbxArray(n.id, $event.checked, 'notification')"

This way it can work for multiple checkboxes arrays in one form.
Just set the name of the controls array to connect each time.

```js
constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private http: Http,
  private codeTableService: CodeTablesService) {

  this.codeTableService.getnotifications().subscribe(response => {
      this.notifications = response;
    })
    ...
}


createForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    notification: this.fb.array([])...
  });
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.createForm();
}

updateChkbxArray(id, isChecked, key) {
  const chkArray = < FormArray > this.form.get(key);
  if (isChecked) {
    chkArray.push(new FormControl(id));
  } else {
    let idx = chkArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == id);
    chkArray.removeAt(idx);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <section class="checkbox-section text-center" *ngIf="notifications  && notifications.length > 0">
    <label class="example-margin">Notifications to send:</label>
    <p *ngFor="let n of notifications; let i = index" formArrayName="notification">
      <mat-checkbox class="checkbox-margin" (change)="updateChkbxArray(n.id, $event.checked, 'notification')" value="n.id">{{n.description}}</mat-checkbox>
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

At the end you are getting to save the form with array of original records id's to save/update.
[image: The UI View]

[image: The relevat part of the json of the form]

> Will be happy to have any remarks for improvement.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Select with multiple flag in Material accomplishes this out of box https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples

Answer (score 1):

Component:

```
formGroup: FormGroup;

games = [
  { keyword: 'hots', score: 9 },
  { keyword: 'xcom', score: 9 },
  { keyword: 'fallout', score: 8 }
];

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.formGroup = this.fb.group(
    this.games.reduce((obj, game) => {
      obj[game.keyword] = [false];
      return obj;
    }, {})
  );

  const enabledGames$ = this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
    map(value =>
      Object.entries(value)
        .filter(([key, enabled]) => enabled)
        .map(([key]) => 
          this.games.find(({ keyword }) => keyword === key)
        )
    )
  );
}
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div *ngFor="let control of formGroup.controls | keyvalue">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      [formControlName]="control.key">
    <label>
      {{ control.key }}
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

### With two way binding

**my.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

  <div formGroupName="options">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="myVal1">My Value 1</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="myVal2">My Value 2</mat-checkbox>
  </div>


  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

**my.component.ts**

```
export class ClientStatementReportComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      options: new FormGroup({
        myVal1: new FormControl(false),
        myVal2: new FormControl(false)
      }),
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const options = this.formGroup.value.options;
    const result = Object.keys(options).filter(key => options[key])
    // is array of checked elements e.g. ["myVal1"]
  }
}
```

### With one way binding (to form state)

**my.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">

  <mat-checkbox value="val-1" (change)="selectOption($event)">Value 1</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox value="val-2" (change)="selectOption($event)">Value 2</mat-checkbox>
 
</form>
```

**my.component.ts**

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  formGroup: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      options: new FormControl([]),
    });
  }

  selectOption($event: MatCheckboxChange) {
    const value = $event.source.value;
    const optionControl = this.formGroup.controls['options']
    const options = optionControl.value as [];

    if(checked){
      optionControl.setValue([...options, value])
    } else {
      optionControl.setValue(options.filter(option => option !== value))
    }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve the answer :)

Comment: Works well. A little fix for one-way binding though:
`if($event.checked){`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a set of directives that can accomplish this easily, with nothing more than a standard FormGroup, and minimal effect to your template:

[StackBlitz Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8q2v2e?file=src/checkbox-array.directive.ts)

Inside your component, define your FormGroup:

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({
  resultArray: new FormControl([])
})
```

Inside your template, set your `formControlName` on the div wrapping all of your checkboxes, with the new `checkboxArray` directive as well.

On each checkbox, set `checkboxArrayKey` to the value you want to include if this checkbox is selected

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <!-- ... -->
  <div checkboxArray formControlName="resultArray">
    <div *ngFor="let option of checkboxOptions">
      <input type="checkbox" [checkboxArrayKey]="option.value">
      <label>{{option.label}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

Your form control will now have a value reflecting only the checkboxes that are selected

The directive itself is a little rough and could probably use some cleanup:

```
import { AfterContentInit, ContentChildren, Directive, ElementRef, forwardRef, Input, OnDestroy, Output, QueryList, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";
import { merge, of, Subject, takeUntil } from "rxjs";

@Directive({
    selector: 'input[type=checkbox][checkboxArrayKey]',
    host: {
        '(change)': 'onChange($event.target.checked)', 
        '(blur)': 'onTouched()'
    }
})
export class CheckboxArrayKey {
    @Input("checkboxArrayKey") key: any;
    parent?: CheckboxArrayValueAccessor;
    state: boolean = false;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef) {
    }

    writeValue(value: boolean) {
        this.state = value;
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.element.nativeElement, "checked", value);
    }

    onChange(value: boolean) {
        this.state = value;
        this.parent?.onChange();
    }

    onTouched() {
        this.parent?.onTouched();
    }
    
    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
        this.renderer.setProperty(this.element.nativeElement, "disabled", isDisabled)
    }
}


export const CHECKBOX_ARRAY_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => CheckboxArrayValueAccessor),
    multi: true
}


@Directive({
    selector: '[checkboxArray][formControlName], [checkboxArray][formControl], [checkboxArray][ngModel]',
    providers: [CHECKBOX_ARRAY_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class CheckboxArrayValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor, AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
    @ContentChildren(CheckboxArrayKey, {descendants: true}) checkboxes?: QueryList<CheckboxArrayKey>;

    private state: any[] = [];
    private destroy = new Subject<void>();
    private onWriteValue = new Subject<void>();
    private _onChange = (_: any) => {};
    private _onTouched = () => {};

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        // Checkboxes will be defined by now - the if is a hack to resolve the potential undefined state
        if (this.checkboxes) {
            merge(of(0), this.checkboxes.changes, this.onWriteValue).pipe(
                takeUntil(this.destroy),
            ).subscribe({ next: () => {
                this.linkChildren();
            }});
        }
    }

    private linkChildren() {
        var me = this;
        var lastState = this.state;

        this.checkboxes?.forEach(chk => { 
            chk.writeValue(lastState.indexOf(chk.key) > -1); 
            chk.parent = me;
        });

        //Hack to avoid changes after a change detection cycle
        Promise.resolve(null).then(() => this.onChange());
    }

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
            this.state = obj;
            this.onWriteValue.next();
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
        this._onChange = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
        this._onTouched = fn;
    }

    setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.checkboxes?.forEach(chk => chk.setDisabledState(isDisabled));
    }

    onChange() {
        this._onChange(this.checkboxes?.filter(chk => chk.state).map(chk => chk.key) || []);
    }

    onTouched() {
        this._onTouched();
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy.next();
        this.destroy.complete();
        this.onWriteValue.complete();
    }
}
```

But it makes for extremely versatile and unobtrusive implementations.

Comment: Works quite well when setting up a new form but if the form already has an existing value its not populating the values during linkChildren.

Solved this by adding...  

    @Input()
    public formControl: FormControl|null = null;   

            lastState = (this.formControl?.value!).toString().split(',');

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late!

I don't know if is the best implementation, but works fine to me. Works with Angular Material too. For me, is simple to read and undestand.

In the example I set and FormBuilder value.
Inside a <form [formGroup]="formData">

**form-body.component.html**

```
<section>
  <label for="pepperoni">Pepperoni</label>
  <input id="pepperoni" type="checkbox" (change)="addValue($event)" value="pepperoni">
  <label for="extracheese">Extra Cheese</label>
  <input id="extracheese" type="checkbox" (change)="addValue($event)" value="extracheese">
  <label for="mushroom">Mushroom</label>
  <input id="mushroom" type="checkbox" (change)="addValue($event)" value="mushroom">
</section>
```

**form-boby.component.ts**

```
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.formData = this.formBuilder.group({
    toppings: ['']
   });
}

addValue($event: any) {
const value = $event.target.value;
const checked = $event.target.checked;
const checkValues: string[] = this.formData.get('toppings')?.value || []

if (checked) {
  checkValues.push(value);
} else {
  const index = checkValues.indexOf(value)
  checkValues.splice(index, 1)
}
this.formData.get('toppings')?.setValue(checkValues)
console.log(this.formData.get('toppings')?.value)
}
```

For use with Angular Material, you must need to change "target" in function to "source".

I hope it is useful for someone!

Answer (score -1):

Add my 5 cents) 
My question model

```
{
   name: "what_is_it",
   options:[
     {
      label: 'Option name',
      value: '1'
     },
     {
      label: 'Option name 2',
      value: '2'
     }
   ]
}
```

template.html

```
<div class="question"  formGroupName="{{ question.name }}">
<div *ngFor="let opt of question.options; index as i" class="question__answer" >
  <input 
    type="checkbox" id="{{question.name}}_{{i}}"
    [name]="question.name" class="hidden question__input" 
    [value]="opt.value" 
    [formControlName]="opt.label"
   >
  <label for="{{question.name}}_{{i}}" class="question__label question__label_checkbox">
      {{opt.label}}
  </label>
</div>
```

component.ts

```
 onSubmit() {
    let formModel = {};
    for (let key in this.form.value) {
      if (typeof this.form.value[key] !== 'object') { 
        formModel[key] = this.form.value[key]
      } else { //if formgroup item
        formModel[key] = '';
        for (let k in this.form.value[key]) {
          if (this.form.value[key][k])
            formModel[key] = formModel[key] + k + ';'; //create string with ';' separators like 'a;b;c'
        }
      }
    }
     console.log(formModel)
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to accomplish this using a FormArray of FormGroups. The FormGroup consists of two controls. One for the data and one to store the checked boolean.

**TS**

```
options: options[] = [{id: 1, text: option1}, {id: 2, text: option2}];

this.fb.group({
  options: this.fb.array([])
})    

populateFormArray() {    
  this.options.forEach(option => {                       
    let checked = ***is checked logic here***;            
    this.checkboxGroup.get('options').push(this.createOptionGroup(option, checked))
  });       
}  

createOptionGroup(option: Option, checked: boolean) {
  return this.fb.group({      
    option: this.fb.control(option),
    checked: this.fb.control(checked)
  });
}
```

**HTML**

This allows you to loop through the options and bind to the corresponding checked control.

```
<form [formGroup]="checkboxGroup">
  <div formArrayName="options" *ngFor="let option of options; index as i">   
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checked" />
      {{ option.text }}
    </div>
  </div>       
</form>
```

**Output**

The form returns data in the form `{option: Option, checked: boolean}[]`.

You can get a list of checked options using the below code

```
 this.checkboxGroup.get('options').value.filter(el => el.checked).map(el => el.option);
```

Answer (score -1):

Template

```
 <div>
    <input name="fruits" type="checkbox" value="orange" (change)="change($event)">
    <input name="fruits" type="checkbox" value="apple" (change)="change($event)">
    <input name="fruits" type="checkbox" value="banana" (change)="change($event)">
</div>
```

Component

```
    formGroup = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        fruits: [[]]  //["Orange","Banana",...]
      })

    change(event: Event) {
      let target = (event.target as HTMLInputElement);
      let array = (this.formGroup.get(target.name)?.value as Array);
    
      if (target.checked && !array.find(element => {
        return (element === target.value);
      })) {
        array.push(target.value)// element not exists, push (check)
      }
      else {
        array.splice(array.findIndex(element => {
          return (element === target.value);//delete element (uncheck)
        }), 1)
      }
    }
```

This is how I would do it, although I always use Angular Material List

https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview

Everything comes from the factory for these tasks

Answer (score -1):

Below code can also help you render dynamically received data from API call.

In your component class file: (Data from API call)

```
this.adminService.getSystemConfigs().subscribe(configs => {
    this.systemConfigs = configs;

    this.createForm();
    this.getUserConfigs();
});

getUserConfigs(): void {
    this.adminService.getUserConfigs().subscribe(configs => {
        this.userConfigs = configs;
        this.patchForm();
    });
}
```

In your component class file: (Data is hardcoded)

```
this.systemConfigs = [
    {
        id: '123',
        key: 'Is allowed to edit',
    },
    {
        id: '456',
        key: 'Is allowed to publish',
    }
];

this.userConfigs = [
    {
        id: '456',
        key: 'Is allowed to publish',
    }
];

get configsArr() {
    return this.userForm.get('configs') as FormArray;
}

createForm(): void {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        ...Your other form fields,
        configs: this.formBuilder.array(this.systemConfigs.map(_ => this.formBuilder.control(false))),
    });
}

patchForm(): void {
    // Patch config values
    this.systemConfigs.map((sysConfig, i) => {
        // Get list of user config ID's to setvalues for checkbox
        const userConfigIds = this.userConfigs.map(userConfig => userConfig.id);
        if (userConfigIds.includes(sysConfig.id)) {
            this.configsArr.at(i).patchValue(true);
        }
    });
}

onSubmit(): void {
    const selectedConfig = this.userForm.value.configs
        .map((checked, i) => ({ id: checked ? this.systemConfigs[i].id : null }))
        .filter(value => value.id !== null);
    // selectedConfig can now be send as payload to API call.
}
```

Your HTML will look like this.

```
<label class="form-label option" formArrayName="configs" *ngFor="let configControl of configsArr.controls; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i" />
        {{ systemConfigs[i].key }}
</label>
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-c3bauv?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Answer (score -2):

**TEMPLATE PART:-**

```
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="options">Options:</label>
         <div *ngFor="let option of options">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"
                   name="options"
                   value="{{option.value}}"
                   [(ngModel)]="option.checked"
                                />
                  {{option.name}}
                  </label>
              </div>
              <br/>
         <button (click)="getselectedOptions()"  >Get Selected Items</button>
     </div>
```

**CONTROLLER PART:-**

```
        export class Angular2NgFor {

          constructor() {
             this.options = [
              {name:'OptionA', value:'first_opt', checked:true},
              {name:'OptionB', value:'second_opt', checked:false},
              {name:'OptionC', value:'third_opt', checked:true}
             ];


             this.getselectedOptions = function() {
               alert(this.options
                  .filter(opt => opt.checked)
                  .map(opt => opt.value));
                }
             }

        }
```

Comment: Hi @EchoLogic   .. Please let me know in case of any query

Comment: This is not using ReactiveForms but regular forms so doesn't answer the question