# How to bind a list of UUIDs to a FormArray of mat-checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular-material

In an Angular 7 SPA, I'm tasked with giving the user a list of checkboxes, which will bind to UUIDs.

```
<ng-container formArrayName="mappedSegmentUuids">
  <div *ngFor="let seg of allsegments; let i = index">
    <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="i" [value]="seg.uuid">{{seg.mydescription}}</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

While I can set the 'value' on the mat-checkbox, this will revert to true/false as soon as the user interacts with the checkbox. How can I bind an arbitrary value to the "checked" state of a mat-checkbox?

**Edit**
Added https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6pzu2e to illustrate issue.

Comment: I do not believe you can override [value] like that on a checkbox. You will need to do some filtering to find out which items have been selected and then access their `uuid`. Here is an excellent read outlining a similar implementation with Angular 7 --> https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular

Comment: My understanding is that the CheckboxControlValueAccessor  should update the 'checked' state of the element instead of value. When toggling the checkbox (stackblitz), the value attribute remains, yet the FormGroup value goes to true/false

Comment: You are correct. This might make for an interesting read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927167/angular-reactiveforms-producing-an-array-of-checkbox-values