# How do I filter a list sorted from Checkbox Values in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I've seen a few checkbox ideas and strategies, but can't seem to get this to work in my particular case.

I am newer to Angular but am trying to build a workout webapp. What I am trying to do is use checkboxes to filter which workouts appear in the workout list (workout list is displayed using an `ngFor`).

Currently, I have a **WorkoutListComponent** that displays the list using the `ngFor` (shortened for simplicity):

```
<div
  *ngFor="let workout of workouts"
  class="workout__list"
>

  <h2 class="workout__item--title">{{ workout.title }}</h2>
  <h3 class="workout__item--specs-heading">{{ workout.type }}</h3>
  <h3 class="workout__item--specs-heading">{{ workout.duration}}</h3>
  <h3 class="workout__item--specs-heading">{{ workout.phase }}</h3>
</div>
```

Within my `ts`, I have the following:

```
...
workouts: any;

constructor(private workoutService: WorkoutService) {
  this.workoutService.getWorkouts().subscribe(res => {
    this.workouts = res;
    console.log("List Comp: ", this.workouts);
  });
}
```

The `workouts: any` is coming from my `workout.service`. This is the same service that holds my mock workout data and runs the function to get and sort workouts. The `workout.service` is also making an observable with `BehaviorSubject` so I can subscribe to it in the above `WorkoutListComponent`.
**WorkoutService**

```
selectedWorkouts: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  workouts: Workout[] = [
    new Workout( ... dummy text for workouts ... ),
    new Workout( ... dummy text for workouts ... ),
    new Workout( ... dummy text for workouts ... )
  ];
 constructor() {
    this.selectedWorkouts = new BehaviorSubject(this.workouts);
  }

getWorkouts() {
  return this.selectedWorkouts.asObservable();
}

filterWorkouts(phase: any[]) {
  console.log("SERVICE: ", phase);

    // I want the filter to take place here and put the filtered items back into the `this.workouts` array
 }
}
```

So far what I have tried code that doesn't work, where in the `filterWorkouts()` function, I take in the phase and specialty, and then filter `this.workouts` storing it into `this.workouts`. Since `this.workouts` is displayed in the list item, the idea is that this would work. Unfortunately it has not worked the way I wanted to. This code is at the bottom of the `src/app/features/workouts-page/workoutservice/workout.service.ts` [in the attached stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4rezan)

The way I am currently receiving checkbox data is through my `WorkoutFilter` component. I am taking the checked property keyvalues and storing them within an object array rather than only using `true or false` properties as found [in this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927167/angular-reactiveforms-producing-an-array-of-checkbox-values/52370903#52370903) . The WorkoutFilter Component is found [in the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4rezan) in `src/app/features/workouts-page/workouts/workouts-filter`.

All I'm trying to do is find the best way to filter this list depending on the checkbox values.

- The checkbox values are coming through the WorkoutFilter component.
- The Workout list I want to display after being filtered is the WorkoutList.
- I am currently using an apply button for the form. When submitted, the data is made into an object with strings to hold the values of the checkboxes. This can be seen in the WorkoutFilter component

  If there is a better method to doing this, maybe even using id's , I am all ears.

[Here is the StackBlitz code.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4rezan) I removed a few components such as the header and sidenav to make viewing of the issue easier.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend when you are working with multiple checkboxes, to use the SelectionModel from angular collections. Try not using reactive forms with multiple checkboxs control for filters like that, SelectionModel makes it so easier.

Here's the stackblitz, hope it helps.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-4rezan-yqxkyv

code:

html:

```
<h4>Phase</h4>
<div class="checkbox">
    <span *ngFor="let phase of phaseOptions">
      <mat-checkbox
        color="warn"
        type="checkbox"
        (click)="phaseSelection.toggle(phase)"
      >
        {{ phase }}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </span>
</div>

<h4>Specialty</h4>
<div class="checkbox">
    <span *ngFor="let specialty of specialtyOptions">
      <mat-checkbox
        color="warn"
        type="checkbox"
        (click)="specialtySelection.toggle(specialty)"
      >
        {{ specialty }}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </span>
</div>
<button (click)="applyFilter()">Apply</button>
```

ts:

```
  specialtySelection = new SelectionModel<string>(true);
  phaseSelection = new SelectionModel<string>(true);

  applyFilter() {
    this.workoutService.filterWorkouts(this.phaseSelection.selected,
         this.specialtySelection.selected);
      }
```

service:

```
filterWorkouts(phases: string[], specialties: string[]) {
  // do Filter with phases and specialties
  if (phases.length === 0 && specialties.length === 0) {
     this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
  } else {
    const byPhase = (workout) => phases.some(phase => workout.phase === phase);
    const bySpecialty = (workout) => specialties.some(specialty => workout.specialty === specialty);
    const workouts = this.workouts.filter(workout => byPhase(workout) && bySpecialty(workout));
    this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
  }
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I had no idea about this!! Thank you so much for your reply. I just have 2 questions. How do I still return the entire full list of no boxes are checked? Also with this, how do I make "and" conditions. So if a phase "Base 1" is checked and a "Road Race", then it shows 2 items instead of just one that fits both categories. I imagine it isn't too hard of a fix. Thank you again for your reply and answer

Comment: I got the empty boxes array to work fairly well by wrapping it in an `if` statement. : `if(phases.length === 0 && specialties.length === 0) {
      const workouts = this.workouts;
      this.selectedWorkouts.next(workouts);
    } else .... `. I imagine the rest will be similar...

Comment: For the empty list is an `if`. I edited the code. And for both filters, change `||` to `&&`.