# How to reset reactive Angular Material form in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular9

I am trying to reset a reactive form created by Angular Material (except the checkbox). I've tried to use `this.formdata.reset()`. It is resetting the form but it's making it `touched`. So I used `this.formdata.markAsUntouched()` but it's not making anything different. Here is my code below:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, FormControl, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class FormComponent implements OnInit{

  public states = [];

  Gender: model[] = [{value: 'M', option: 'Male'}, {value: 'F', option: 'Female'}];
  Vehicles: model[] = [{value: '2 wheelers', option: '2 wheelers'}, {value: '4 wheelers', option: '4 wheelers'}];

  constructor(private _statesService: StatesService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  // Initialize each field of form with FormBuilder
  formdata = this.fb.group({
    name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]], phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(12)]],
    gender: ['', Validators.required], vehicles: new FormArray([],Validators.required)
  });

  // Retreiving values of form field
  get Name()
  {return this.formdata.get('name');}

  get Phone()
  {return this.formdata.get('phone');}

  get Vehiclesmethod()
  {return this.formdata.get('vehicles');}

  get Genderval()
  {return this.formdata.get('gender');}

  onCheckChange(event) {
    const formArray: FormArray = this.formdata.get('vehicles') as FormArray;

    /* Selected */
    if(event.target.checked){
      // Add a new control in the arrayForm
      formArray.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
    }
    /* unselected */
    else{
      // find the unselected element
      let i: number = 0;

      formArray.controls.forEach((ctrl: FormControl) => {
        if(ctrl.value == event.target.value) {
          // Remove the unselected element from the arrayForm
          formArray.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
  }
  @ViewChild('f') private f: NgForm;
  // Submit method
  onSubmit()
  {
    if(this.formdata.invalid){return ;}
    console.log(this.formdata.value);
    alert('submitted');
    // Reset form
    this.formdata.reset();
    this.formdata.markAsUntouched();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formdata" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm"> 
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <p>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="field_size">
                            <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                            <input type="text" matInput formControlName="name">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="Name.errors?.required">Name required</mat-error>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="Name.errors?.minlength">Minimum 3 characters required</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <p>
                        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="field_size">
                            <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
                            <input type="tel" matInput appPhoneMask formControlName="phone" maxlength="12">
                            <mat-error *ngIf="Phone.errors?.required">Phone number required</mat-error>
                            <mat-error *ngIf="Phone.errors?.minlength">Number is less than 10 digits</mat-error>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Gender</label><br>
                    <mat-radio-group formControlName="gender">
                        <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let g of Gender; let i = index" [value]="g.value">{{ g.option }}</mat-radio-button>
                    </mat-radio-group><br>
                    <small *ngIf="Genderval.errors?.required" style="color: red;">Please select Gender</small>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <label>Vehicles</label><br>
                    <div class="form-inline">
                        <span class="custome-control custom-checkbox mr-sm-2" *ngFor="let v of Vehicles,let i=index">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="{{i}}" [value]="v.value" (change)="onCheckChange($event)">
                            <label for="{{i}}" class="custom-control-label">{{v.option}}</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit" class="button" [disabled]="!formdata.valid">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**NOTE:** The value is getting emptied for every fields in the `FormBuilder` part and also in the view part. But the checkbox in view part it's showing still checked.

Please help me out I've tried many ways but nothing is working fine.

Comment: You need to pass `true`/`false` values to the checkbox. You're passing `v.value` which is a string (aka a truthy value) which is why your checkbox is always checked. Dealing with checkboxes dynamically with `formControl` is tricky. You can check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261847/9739129) if you want to dynamically produce boolean values and then map them to your string values.

Comment: tried now still it's getting remained checked !!

Comment: Why are you not using formControlName directive for checkbox, if you are using reactive form

Comment: @Chellappanவ yeah i know that but it was making both the checkboxes checked but the values weren't passed

Comment: You mean if you use reactive way?

Comment: @Chellappanவ yes

Comment: Can you create stackblitz ?

Comment: ok am sharing the link after creating in stackblitz

Answer (score 3):

You can get a reference to your ngForm like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="commentForm" **#commentNgForm="ngForm"** (submit)="replyTicket()"></form>
```

and then in your component get this refence with @ViewChild as this

```
 @ViewChild('commentNgForm') commentNgForm!: NgForm;
```

and finally you can use then in your method like this

```
this.commentNgForm.resetForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if will work for entire form, but definitelly is ok for each FormControl. You need to specify in options place to not emit an event after changes.

```
this.formdata.reset('', {emitEvent: false});
```

after this, if your form is still marked as touched, try your solution + check form changes:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

this.formdata.markAsUntouched();
this.cd.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the resetForm() method.
So instead of writing `this.formdata.reset()` write `this.formdata.resetForm()`, and no need to use the markAsUntouched

Source: https://itnext.io/to-reset-a-form-or-to-resetform-555d3da47c52

Comment: it gives an error. like there is no resetForm() method