# Bind data to checkbox in angular material table using formcontrol. Data is available as list of true,false values

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, form-control, angular-material-table

**HTML**

````
<ng-container matColumnDef="view">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>View</mat-header-cell>
       <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index"> 
          <mat-checkbox formControlName="view" (change)=updateCheckedList(element)>
         </mat-checkbox>
       </mat-cell>
</ng-container>  ```

**TS**
````

view = [true,false,false,true]

```
createRoleForm(): FormGroup
  {
      return this._formBuilder.group({
          id              : [this.role.id],
          name            : [this.role.name],
         // view : 

      });
  }
```

I need to check the check boxes which are in the material table(view column) according to values of view list.

Comment: I think you looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771219/4799922

Answer (score -2):

you cant do like this because your form Controller is having only one control fot the view
so you need to you ng model it helps to you like this

```
    <ng-container matColumnDef="view">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>View</mat-header-cell>
           <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i=index"> 
              <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checked" 
               [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
               (change)=updateCheckedList(element)>
             </mat-checkbox>
           </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

inside the element use create a attribute called checked that's it

way 2 -
if you want to do with an form controlled you need to use form array that's it