# Reactive forms - Adding dynamic checkboxes to the expansion panel component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a simple movie list app and I am using a checkbox list to filter my movie list by genre.

I succeeded without the reactive forms approach.
I was wondering how I could continue it using the reactive forms approach.

The code below shows how my expected functionality looks (without reactive forms):

[demo-link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s4rnak?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffilters%2Fcheckbox-list.component.html)

I've tried implementing reactive forms, but I'm not sure how to do it:

[try-link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zkzzyx?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffilters%2Fcheckbox-list.component.html)

Thanks.

Comment: did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40937827/3395330

Answer (score 0):

You have to watch the from, when its value changes do your job.

```js
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe({
    next: (value) => {
        // do your job here
    },
});
```